How can I count cominations of variables in R?
I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of combinations across two variables in a data frame in R.
If I have the following dataframe:
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 v2 = c("B", "C", "C", "A"))

v1  v2

A   B
A   C
B   C
B   A

I'm trying to count the combinations of the two variables, where "AB" would be treated the same as "BA".  I would like to end up with something like this:
comb   n

A,B    2
A,C    1
B,C    1

I tried using
count(df, v1, v2)

but it counts AB and BA separately.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

You need to first paste the two columns together with sorting, then count.
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(combn = paste0(sort(c(v1, v2)), collapse = ",")) |> 
  count(combn) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  combn     n
  <chr> <int>
1 A,B       2
2 A,C       1
3 B,C       1


Using pmin and pmax may help for this simple example:
mutate(df, v12=paste0(pmin(v1, v2), pmax(v1, v2))) |>
  count(v12)

  v12 n
1  AB 2
2  AC 1
3  BC 1


Note that it is important to use .$v1 rather than just v1 here because otherwise the v2= would use the revised v1 just computed rather than the original v1.
df %>% count(v1 = pmin(v1, v2), v2 = pmax(.$v1, v2))

If it is OK to use V1 and V2 (upper case) on output then it can be simplified to:
count(df, V1 = pmin(v1, v2), V2 = pmax(v1, v2))

